# How can I calculate $(1+\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n$ being $n\in{\mathbb{Z}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, angle

How can I calculate $(1+\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n$ being $n\in{\mathbb{Z}}$ ?

---

I think that I can use the half angle formulas for it, but I don't know how. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know that $\cos x+i\sin x=e^{ix}$?

Comment: Does $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta $ help ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the half-angle identities
$$
1+\cos(θ)=2\cos^2(θ/2),\\
\sin(θ)=2\cos(θ/2)\sin(θ/2)
$$
and the Euler-Moivre formulas as per the comments. This gives an expression where all powers are of real numbers, with a phase factor depending on $n$.

Answer (score 2):

You have\begin{align}\bigl(1+\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)^n
&=\left(1+e^{i\theta}\right)^n\\&=\left(2e^{i\theta/2}\frac{e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta/2}}2\right)^n\\&=\left(2e^{i\theta/2}\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)^n\\&=2^n\cos^n\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\left(\cos\left(\frac{n\theta}2\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\theta}2\right)\right).\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Start from $$\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$$
Then $$(1+e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta/2}(e^{i\theta/2}+e^{-i\theta/2})^n$$
Now we use $$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
Then $$(1+e^{i\theta})^n=2^ne^{in\theta/2}\cos^n\frac\theta 2\\=2^n\left(\cos\frac{n\theta}2+i\sin\frac{n\theta}2\right)\cos^n\frac\theta 2$$

Answer (score 1):

The figure shows the sum of the unit vectors $1+e^{i\theta}=re^{i\phi}$.

[image]

As we have an isosceles triangle,

$$\phi=\dfrac\theta2$$ and $$r=2\cos\phi.$$

Hence

$$(1+\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^n=2^n\cos^n(\phi)\,(\cos(n\phi)+i\sin(n\phi)).$$

Answer (score 0):

well,
$$\cos\theta+i\sin\theta=e^{i\theta}$$
so your question is
$$(1+e^{i\theta})^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ik\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

Another trick:

Your expression is
\begin{aligned}
(1+e^{i\theta})^n & = \big(e^{i\theta / 2}(e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta/2})\big)^n \\
&= e^{ni\theta/2}(2\cos(\theta/2))^n\\
&= 2^n \big(\cos(n\theta/2) + i\sin(n\theta/2)\big)\cdot \cos^n(\theta/2)
\end{aligned}